# Check to see if UIButton was pushed

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have four UI buttons and I want different things to happen based on which button the user pushes. I've tried using a boolean to check if a button is pressed, but it doesn't seem to be working. The boolean code for each button is basically:

```
 -(IBAction)FirstChoice:(id)sender
{
 wasClicked = YES;
}
```

then in the main function itself:

```
if(wasClicked)
{
    returnView.text = @"Test";
}
```

however when I push any of the buttons, the test text doesn't appear.

Comment: The IBActions are supossed to do the text change. If you use `returnView.text = @"Test";` inside the `FirstChoice` method, does it work? Btw, did you assign the IBAction to the UIButton (CTRL+drag)? You better show all the involved code, sometimes you **think** the error is there, but there's somewhere else actually (I'm thinking about your `main` function somehow).

Comment: why you are not setting the text in this function only-(IBAction)FirstChoice:(id)sender

Comment: Use break point and check your button's method is call or not ???

Comment: @AlejandroIván I'm trying to make it so multiple presses of the same button will give different results (think a dialogue tree). Vizlix this is also why I'm not setting the text inside the IBAction.

Comment: @user2988882 yes, but if you set the text in the IBAction, does it work? This is just to see if your action is correctly connected with the Storyboard/XIB.

Comment: @AlejandroIván yes it does.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a common "Touch up inside "outlet function for all buttons... and Set different tags for each buttons.. for example

```
-(IBAction)FirstChoice:(id)sender // common "Touch up inside" action for all four buttons
{
 UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender; //assuming that you have set tag for buttons

      if(btn.tag==94)
        {
          //Do any thing for button 1
         }
       else if (btn.tag==93)
        {
          returnView.text = @"Test";
          //Do any thing for button 2
         }
       else if (btn.tag==92)
        {
          //Do any thing for button 3
         }
        else
           {
             //Do any thing for button 4

            }


}
```

Comment: `UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender.tag;` I believe this is wrong, `tag` doesn't return an `UIButton`, this will probably crash. Doing this kind of conversion is not recommended also, it would be better to define the method like `- (IBAction)FirstChoice:(UIButton *)sender { ... }`

Comment: @AlejandroIván- I have used it in many of the apps so there is no chance of crashing mate.

Comment: I was thinking it because you are casting `sender.tag` which is an `NSInteger` to a `UIButton *` and then calling `tag` again. Basically, as you're calling `btn.tag` in the if-then-else statements, you don't have to call it when assigning the `UIButton *` or vice-versa. It will probably crash if you call `btn.tag` because `NSInteger` doesn't have a `tag` method, it's defined in the superclass `UIView`.

Comment: @AlejandroIván- Yes mate you are right i have mistakenly  written (UIButton *)sender.tag- which was wrong.. I have edited the post

Comment: @Vizllx this works but is there a way to do this where the if/elseif/else checks for the tags are inside of my main function? I want to be able to have each button spit out different answers to the if/else based on how far the user has progressed (think dialogue tree).
I tried just putting it straight into main but it doesn't like that (because of (id)sender and sender not being declared otherwise). Removing any reference to sender and it will work but then crash upon button press

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same approach as Vizllx answer, but a little bit clear. This assumes you have already set `tags` for every button that will invoke your `IBAction`. As this method will be invoked from UIButtons, I changed the type of the argument. If you need it to be called from another kind of objects, change it to `id` and do the manual casting.

```
- (IBAction)FirstChoide:(UIButton *)sender
{
    const int BUTTON_TAG_1 = 92; // Identifier (tag) from a button
    const int BUTTON_TAG_2 = 93; // Another one
    // ...


    int tag = sender.tag; // tag returns an NSInteger, so it casts automatically to an int

    switch(tag)
    {
        case BUTTON_TAG_1:
            // Do stuff like setting strings to another elements, for example:
            // returnView.text = @"Test";
            break;

        case BUTTON_TAG_2:
            // Again...
            break;

        default:
            // Any other cases...
    }
}
```